# While dentro de outro While em Java

Tags: java, loop

Estou tentando fazer um while dentro de outro while e após a execução do código dentro do segundo while pergunto se deseja continuar ou não, caso sim, o programa deverá loop do primeiro while. Acontece que o loop só está indo para o segundo while e não para o primeiro. Abaixo está o código:

```
public class ExercicioCalculadora2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int soma, sub, div, multi, num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    String operacao = "";
    boolean continua = true, continua2 = true;
    String pergunta = "";

    System.out.println("CALCULADORA");

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(continua) {

    System.out.print("Digite um numero entre 1 e 4: ");
    num1 = entrada.nextInt();

        if(num1 >= 1 && num1 <=4) {


            while(continua2) {

            System.out.println();   
            System.out.print("Digite outro numero entre 1 e 4: ");
            num2 = entrada.nextInt();

            if(num2 >= 1 && num2 <= 4) {

                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Digite qual operação deseja executar(Soma, Divisão, Subtração ou Multiplicação): ");
                operacao = entrada.next();

                switch(operacao) {

                case "Soma":
                    soma  = num1 + num2;
                    System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + soma);
                    break;

                case "Divisão":
                    div = num1 / num2;
                    System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + div);
                    break;

                case "Subtração":
                    sub = num1 - num2;
                    System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + sub);
                    break;

                case "Multiplicação":
                    multi = num1 * num2;
                    System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + multi);
                    break;

                }   


            }else {
                System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
            }

            System.out.println("Deseja continuar calculando(S ou N)? ");
            pergunta = entrada.next();

                if(pergunta.toUpperCase().equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("FIM DO PROGRAMA");
                    continua = false;
                    continua2 = false;
                }

            }

        }else {
            System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
        }


    }   

}

}
```

Comment: Qual o seu problema? está recebendo algum erro ou precisa de ideia de como se implementa?

Answer (score 1):

A lógica que está a utilizar está excessivamente complicada, e acaba por não ter razão para utilizar 2 `while`s com 2 flags de `continua` diferentes.
Ao invés disso é preferível validar cada numero individualmente e caso não esteja dentro do intervalo pretendido, voltar a pedir com o próprio while que já tem:

```
while(continua) {
    System.out.print("Digite um numero entre 1 e 4: ");
    num1 = entrada.nextInt();
    if(num1 <= 0 || num1 > 4) { //se estiver fora
        System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
        continue; //passa a próxima iteração do while, pedindo tudo de novo
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Digite outro numero entre 1 e 4: ");
    num2 = entrada.nextInt();
    if(num2 <= 0 || num2 > 4) { //se estiver fora
        System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
        continue; //passa a próxima iteração do while, pedindo tudo de novo
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Digite qual operação deseja executar(Soma, Divisão, Subtração ou Multiplicação): ");
    operacao = entrada.next();
    switch(operacao) {
        case "Soma":
            soma  = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + soma);
            break;
        case "Divisão":
            div = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + div);
            break;
        case "Subtração":
            sub = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + sub);
            break;
        case "Multiplicação":
            multi = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("O resultado da soma dos dois numeros é : " + multi);
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Deseja continuar calculando(S ou N)? ");
    pergunta = entrada.next();
    if(pergunta.toUpperCase().equals("N")) {
        System.out.println("FIM DO PROGRAMA");
        continua = false;
    }
}
```

Deixo aqui um pequeno alerta que o texto da operação ficou como `soma` para todas as operações dentro do `switch`.

Nesta solução se o usuário falhar num dos números volta a ter que os introduzir de novo. Isto acontece devido ao `continue`, que faz continuar para a próxima iteração do `while` voltando à leitura do primeiro numero. Alternativamente pode ficar em loop em cada numero até que esse seja introduzido corretamente à custa de um `while` por exemplo:

```
while(continua) {
    System.out.print("Digite um numero entre 1 e 4: ");
    num1 = entrada.nextInt();
    while (num1 <= 0 || num1 > 4) { //enquanto não está dentro do intervalo desejado
        System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
        num1 = entrada.nextInt(); //ler novamente
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Digite outro numero entre 1 e 4: ");
    num2 = entrada.nextInt();

    while(num2 <= 0 || num2 > 4) { //enquanto não está dentro do intervalo desejado
        System.out.println("O numero digitado está fora do padrao, digite novamente!");
        num2 = entrada.nextInt(); //ler novamente
    }

    //resto igual
```

Repare que apesar de ter um `while` dentro do outro não existem duas flags de `continua`. E mesmo os segundos `whiles` são muito pequenos e servem apenas para ler um novo número até que fique no intervalo pretendido.

Em qualquer uma destas duas soluções tem muito menos aninhamento que na sua solução inicial, prezando assim pela simplicidade.

Answer (score -2):

```
while (criteiro){
    int a = 1;
    if (a == 0){
        break;
    }
    while (a != 0){
        a++;
        if (a == 100){
            a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```